# identifying the data type in python

Tags: python

What is the easiest way to find the data type of a variable?

When I work with some image processing libraries, there are a lot of list and arrays.
I'm aware of the following methods:

```
clr = [np.uint8([[[0,255,0 ]]])]
print type(clr)
```

But this simply prints `list`, while I'm looking for a method to identify that its of type `list of numpy array`.

I also know that the following can be done,

```
for x in clr:
     print type(x)
```

Is there some other easy method which I am overlooking?

Comment: but this is a list. also where was `var` declared?

Comment: You are right: It is indeed a list .But my question is if this loss in information about the elements of the list can be avoided?( and `var` should have been `clr` )

Answer (score 0):

`print type(clr)` will print `<type 'list'>` since it is a list.
if You keep

```
clr = np.uint8([[[0,255,0 ]]])
print type(clr)
```

this will give you result as `<type 'numpy.ndarray'>`
or else

```
clr = [np.uint8([[[0,255,0 ]]])]
print type(clr[0])
print type(clr)
```

output will be

```
<type 'numpy.ndarray'>
<type 'list'>
```

Hope you got the point.